# How to migrate down a list of migrations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a rails app and had lots of migration file in it, i have created a functionality few months ago and now i want to remove that functionality by removing model/controller related to it(i have list of migration to be removed that functionality).

I can remove it by `rake db:migration:down VERSION=""` specifying version  and using `rails destroy` but there are around 30-40 migrations/models/controllers related to that functionality.

I want to remove all migrations and maintain that list like migration do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this at first, rollback your migrations to version 0.

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

Then you manually delete your migrations and models, leaving the controllers and views intact.

Hope it helps!